# Why does seq() create both int and num vectors whereas c() never creates int vectors?

Tags: r

I can't figure out why `seq()` can output different classes depending on if decimal points are present in the elements, whereas `c()` always creates a num vector regardless of presence or absence of decimals.

For example:

```
seqDec <- seq(1, 2, 0.5) # num vector
cDec <- c(1, 1.5, 2) # num vector
seqInt <- seq(1, 5) # int vector
cInt <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) # num vector
```

Answer (score 5):

`c` creates a vector by concatenating the elements you give it. By contrast `seq` actually constructs a sequence by generating new numbers based on specific parameters.

So in the case of `c(1, 2, 4, 5)`, since the arguments are `numeric`, so is the result (`class(1)` is `numeric`, not `integer`!). You could generate an `integer` vector by providing *integers*:

```
intvec = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)
```

Cumbersome. But possible.

With `seq`, if you don’t provide a step size (`by` parameter), the function defaults to generating integral values; in this regard it’s equivalent to the `:` operator:

```
intvec = 1 : 5
```

In fact, if you don’t provide a `by` or `length.out` argument, then `seq(from, to)`internally executes `from : to`.